# How to change the format of the index of each zoo element of a list using (x)apply

Tags: r, apply

Here's the setup:

```
    x.date <- as.Date((paste(2003, c(1, 3, 7, 9, 12), 2, sep = "-"))
    x <- zoo(rnorm(5), x.date)
    y.date <- as.Date(paste(2005, c(2, 4, 8, 10, 11), 2, sep = "-"))
    y <- zoo(rnorm(5), y.date)
    xy.list<-list(x,y) 
    xy.list 
    [[1]] 2003-01-02 2003-03-02 2003-07-02 2003-09-02 2003-12-02  
          -1.4804701  0.5280618  0.4619898 -0.5840212 -2.1988442


    [[2]] 2005-02-02 2005-04-02 2005-08-02 2005-10-02 2005-11-02 
          0.82720055 -0.05713144 0.29355203 1.08244510 -1.14746500
```

Here's the answer with a for-loop:

```
        for (i in 1:length(index(xy.list))){
  index(xy.list[[i]])<-as.yearmon(index(xy.list[[i]])) 
}    

 xy.list 
    [[1]] Jan 2003   Mar 2003   Jul 2003   Sep 2003   Dec 2003 
         -1.4804701 0.5280618 0.4619898 -0.5840212 -2.1988442


    [[2]] Feb 2005   Apr 2005   Aug 2005   Oct 2005   Nov 2005 
         0.82720055 -0.05713144 0.29355203 1.08244510 -1.14746500
```

My question is how to use lapply, or possibly mapply, to achieve the same end.

I've tried:

```
lapply(xy.list, function(list,listIdx) 
  {index(list[[listIdx]]} <- as.yearmon(index(list[[listIdx]]))}, 
xy.list, 
index(xy.list))
```

with the following error: `'Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : unused argument (1:2)'`

It appears I'm not getting something into the anonymous function that I think I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zoo series should have unique index values so if you are going to convert from Date to yearmon then the series should be aggregated to keep the index values unique.  For example,

```
lapply(xy.list, aggregate, as.yearmon, mean)
```

or

```
lapply(xy.list, aggregate, as.yearmon, function(x) x[1])
```

Another possibility if its important not to aggregate is to convert it to an xts series:

```
library(xts)
lapply(xy.list, function(x) xts(coredata(x), as.yearmon(index(x))))
```

Comment: To avoid confusion, I changed the example to make the indices unique in the month-year format.  I'm not looking to find the mean, yet, just change the indices' format using one of the apply functions.

Comment: Bingo!  The last suggestion (without aggregation) answers the question.  It's more obvious then what I was attempting in my failed lapply.  I'll have to think about any unintended/unexpected consequences in switching from zoo objects to xts objects.

Comment: Its not necessary to use the last one if there is at most one date in each year/month as then the `mean` solution still works since the mean of one number is itself.  If you want to emphasize that you could use `identity` in place of `mean`.